# Android canvas with GPU

Tags: android, gpu, android-canvas

Since Android canvas is not hardware accelerated (untill 3), I want to use OpenGL to display a texture and use that as canvas.

However I can not find any documentation on how to do this. I know android-doom does it, but it's in C and I'm not familiar with Androidapps in C (also it's very cluttered source).

Comment: You can use OpenGL ES ... here is a nice tuto : http://obviam.net/index.php/opengl-es-with-android-switching-from-canvas-to-opengl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not familiar with OpenGL for android, there is this [excellent video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk). You'll learn the basics, somme common mistakes, how to write very fast code, ... and there is a link to some samples (which I don't remember).